# Print VBA Array in to Excel Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to print a VBA created array into cells of an excel spreadsheet. Percolation and Runoff values keep getting "subscript out of range" errors Am I creating hose arrays correctly? I have merged the calculation and print sub function into one.

```
 NumMonth = 12
 Dim col As Long
 Dim rw As Long
 rw = 4
 col = 13

 Range(Cells(rw, col), Cells(rw + NumMonth - 1, col)).Value = _
    Application.Transpose(WC)

Range(Cells(rw, col + 1), Cells(rw + NumMonth - 1, col + 1)).Value = _
    Application.Transpose(Runoff)

   Range(Cells(rw, col + 2), Cells(rw + NumMonth - 1, col + 2)).Value = _
     Application.Transpose(Percolation)
   End Sub
```

Comment: can you please supply some sample data?

Comment: Month:1-12, Ref Et:0.4, Precip: 0.07, fc:0.3, pwp=0.1, WC(i)=0.15. I dont know of a better way to provide data??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Precip` and `RefET` are always equal, is this ment to be?

```
Precip(i) = Cells(4 + i, 2).Value
RefET(i)  = Cells(4 + i, 2).Value
```

---

Also, when you set the `Runoff` and `Percolation` arrays they do not get set to anything if your if statement is not met (below), and I could meet it with the data provided:

```
If (fc - WC(j - 1) + RefET(i) * dz < Precip(i) * dz) then
```

I'd add somthing to make sure there is always a value in them:

```
If (fc - WC(j - 1) + RefET(i) * dz < Precip(i) * dz) Then
    Runoff(i) = (Precip(i) - (fc - WC(j - 1) + RefET(i)) * dz) * 0.5
    Percolation(i) = (Precip(i) - (fc - WC(i - 1) + RefET(i)) * dz) * 0.5
    WC(j) = fc
Else
    Runoff(i) = 0
    Percolation(i) = 0
    WC(j) = WC(j - 1) + Precip(i) - RefET(i) / dz
End If
```

---

**Once doing this I found out you hadn't `ReDim`'d the `Runoff` and `Percolation` variables.**
you'll need to add the following to your `WaterBalanceRead` sub.

```
ReDim Runoff(1 To NumMonth + 1)
ReDim Percolation(1 To NumMonth + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that data read error! If I use the data I provided you, my arrays will still not set?

Comment: @user1977802 - the last line fixed mine!

Answer (score 2):

Its application.transpose instead of worksheetfunction

```
  Range(Cells(rw, col), Cells(rw + NumMonth - 1, col)).Value = _
      application.Transpose(WC)
```

Here is a test sub

```
Sub test()
Dim myarray As Variant

'this is a 1 row 5 column Array
myarray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

'This will fail because the source and destination are different shapes
Range("A1:A5").Value = myarray


'If you want to enter that array into a 1 column 5 row range like A1:A5

Range("A1:A5").Value = Application.Transpose(myarray)
End Sub
```

You will get an error if you call an array you created in another sub.  The reason for this can be seen in the locals window when you step through your code.  When you run the sub that creates your array it will be shown in locals, when the sub ends it will disappear, meaning it is no longer stored in memory.  To refer to a variable or array from another sub you must pass it.

Passing arrays or variables can be done in different ways here are a few links
[Here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/passingandreturningarrays.htm)
[And Here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx)

Comment: No, application.Tanspose does not work. It is an array created in VBA

Comment: I think I have made the correct adjustments you were recommending to me code (see edits in original post) however, it is still not working. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Is there an error?  You may be running into an issue of using a range not assigned to a sheet.. such as `sheets("sheet1").range("A1:A5").value = application.transpose(wc)`

Comment: yes, it is the same error I was getting previously- invalid procedure or call error. If I change it to "Sheets("sheet1").Range("M5:M22").Value = Application.Transpose(WC)" I still am getting the same error.

Comment: ok, it looks like you're referring to arrays you created in another sub, this will cause an error. I get a compile error, do you have option explicit enabled?

Comment: yes. I have option explicit enabled. yes, my arrays were created in a different sub, I have created a sub just to print them.

Comment: @user1977802. To pass the `WC` array into the other sub you should make sure this variable is defined as a global outside all the subs. This will save your updates to the variable

Comment: I have declared it as global. I have included and edited my full code above.

Comment: I have merged my calculation and print sub function. It all seems to be printing correctly except Percolation() and Runoff(). Am I creating those arrays correctly?